# What does '.template' mean in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I saw such codes in LLVM source codes:

```
template <typename PassT, typename IRUnitT, typename AnalysisManagerT,
          typename... ArgTs, size_t... Ns>
typename PassT::Result
getAnalysisResultUnpackTuple(AnalysisManagerT &AM, IRUnitT &IR,
                             std::tuple<ArgTs...> Args,
                             std::index_sequence<Ns...>) {
  (void)Args;
  return AM.template getResult<PassT>(IR, std::get<Ns>(Args)...);
}
```

It seems not to need to explain the context, because all of the arguments are template arguments.
What confuses me is the body of this function. First, I really can't get what does the first statement do:

```
(void)Args;
```

To my knowledge, this just cast `Args` to void to a temporary variable. And the temporary variable will be desconstructed immediately after this statement. It seems like totally meanningless.

And the second statement confuses me about its grammer:

```
return AM.template getResult<PassT>(IR, std::get<Ns>(Args)...);
```

I really don't know what is the meaning of `.template` stand for. I searched `.template` in the search engine but get nothing. I don't know what does the `.template` do here. And I am wondering why don't implement it just like:

```
return AM.getResult<PassT>(IR, std::get<Ns>(Args)...);
```

What's the difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: The flagged duplicate answers the question in your title.  I can't find a proper duplicate for your other question about the cast to `void`, but it's usually to suppress unused parameter warnings by the compiler.  Doesn't seem necessary in this case though, since `Args` is used.

Comment: @MilesBudnek It is necessary because GCC will warn if the pack expansion is empty and doesn't use `Args` in an instantiation: https://godbolt.org/z/bpzXYi

Comment: @walnut Huh, I didn't even realize a 0-length tuple was legal.  TIL.